# How to change wordpress links on app engine?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I have 2 app engine services named default and WordPress and I dispatched routes. When I go to  appspot.com/**wordpress** it is working but in the other links like appspot.com/**category** instead of appspot.com/wordpress/category

How can I configure WordPress source files or files of WordPress to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by configuring your `dispatch.yaml` file.

As it is stated in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/mapping-custom-domains):

> You can use wildcard mappings with services in App Engine by using the dispatch.yaml file to define request routing to specific services.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/reference/dispatch-yaml#example) you can find a good example of wildcard usage for achieving your purpose. In case you have difficulties implementing it you can share your `dispatch.yaml` file and I will check it out.

**EDIT**:

In case you want to use more than 20 url routing rules there is already a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117266829) created for this. A way you can manage to do your routing without exceeding the limit, would be creating more backend services, rather than a monolithical application and directly route the requests to them using their full target address through your frontend default service. Spliting the architecture would be a good idea in case you need to "trick" somehow the 20 url quota.

Comment: But dispatch.yaml is only limited with 20 urls, I need more. I wrote my dispatch.yaml the below.

dispatch:
  - url: "*/wordpress"
    service: wordpress

  - url: "*/wp-content/*"
    service: wordpress

  - url: "*/wp-includes/*"
    service: wordpress

Comment: You can open a support ticket an request a quota increase.